# Change in image urls from Facebook Graph API response

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

My call was returning results like this all week long:

`https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.0-1/p50x50/21751880_4627831336299_3121335327951633783_n.jpg?_nc_cat=0&oh=72058fff4a6716912eca8ada5a182f9d&oe=5B279686`

Beginning this morning though, my call returns the following which doesn't generate a valid picture.

`https://lookaside.facebook.com/platform/profilepic/?limited_token=QVNtU0FCbG1rNXRXSlFNdm5ZATGVDMFRhbU9sN0duTTlrUUw2b0xRdW1BVmFjbVNTenVpak1RaDdtYVZAGRTB0Y2xmeVUxWlRZAdGpyU2JQb3FFbUlNNTJKRE5hYjltWFB1WTN4THdPejhuSVZAObncZD&height=50&width=50`

WHOIS Result:

```
Registrant Name: Domain Administrator
Registrant Organization: Facebook, Inc.
Registrant Street: 1601 Willow Road, 
Registrant City: Menlo Park
Registrant State/Province: CA
Registrant Postal Code: 94025
Registrant Country: US
Registrant Phone: +1.6505434800
```

`dig ns lookaside.facebook.com` returns

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
lookaside.facebook.com. 902 IN  CNAME   scontent.xx.fbcdn.net.
```

Comment: Search Stackoverflow because the question have been asked like 20 times this week

Comment: @WizKid maybe provide a link since I obviously can't find anything other than phishing questions relating to `fbsbx`